# Strange results from tic / toc in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, benchmarking

I'm checking the running time of a function using tic/toc. I write the following in the command window (and execute it simultaneously):

```
tic
res = checkFunc('case2736sp',1:3000);
toc
Elapsed time is 0.080491 seconds.
```

where checkFunc returns a 2736x2500 full matrix.

What puzzles me is that I have to wait almost 20 seconds for the output saying the run time is only 80 ms.

Does anyone have a clue why this is?

Comment: maybe checkFunc calls `tic` internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that tic/toc's internal counter is getting reset somehow during execution. Try it like this:

```
t = tic
res = checkFunc('case2736sp',1:3000);
toc(t)
```